# CakePHP Using Digest Authenticate: login succeeds without password after logout

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, digest-authentication

I am using CakePHP to create a simple app and I decided to use Digest Authenticate since I can't get an SSL certificate and don't want passwords posted in plain-text by a form.

So it's all working nicely, login, logout, everything works according to login status. However after logging out when I go to login again it logs in automatically without asking for a password or username. This makes it impossible to change accounts until I've been logged out for some period of time(a day or so?) and it asks for a username and password again. It also is a security risk if I am using a public computer and don't want the next guy logging into my account all willy nilly without even a password prompt.

My question, is there a setting in Cake that I am missing or is this my browser remembering my credentials and offering them up when the app asks for them. I feel like logging out should clear the credentials. I have tried in Chrome and Firefox both with the same result, I am not checking any "remember my password" boxes either.

My Auth component intiation:

```
public $components = array('Session', 'RequestHandler', 'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array('Digest'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'),
        ));
```

Login Function:

```
public function login() {
//No longer Auth Magic
 if ($this->Auth->login()) {
   return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index'));
 } else {
   $this->Session->setFlash(__('Username or password is incorrect'), 'default', array(), 'auth');
 }
   $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Logout Function:

```
public function logout() {
   $this->Auth->logout();
   return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());

}
```

So any ideas? The only other thing I should mention is that I had to include DigestAuthenticate.php manually in order to use use the DigestAuthenticate::password function, Cake was throwing some errors saying that the DigestAuthenticate class didn't exist. See the issue here: http://ask.cakephp.org/questions/view/digestauthenticate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the CakePHP Book [[here]](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#logging-users-out):

> Logging out users that logged in with Digest or Basic auth is
>   difficult to accomplish for all clients. Most browsers will retain
>   credentials for the duration they are still open. Some clients can be
>   forced to logout by sending a 401 status code. Changing the
>   authentication realm is another solution that works for some clients.

That's probably not what you wanted to hear, but...

Comment: Well there you have it, can't believe I missed that when reading through the book looking for the solution to this. Thanks!